# How to ensure a feature is installed during a Windows Installer AdminInstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am using WiX to create a moderately complex installer. I have a Level 0 Feature that I would like to install conditionally, but also always during an Admin install, to make patching through admin images easier. I've tried several things:

1. Setting a property before the AdminUISequence's CostFinalize action (which is when [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) claims the Condition table is evaluated). The condition in that case looks like:

   `<Condition Level="1">( VersionNT >= 601 AND NOT FASTINSTALL = "1" ) OR INSTALLCONDFEATURE = "1"</Condition>`

   where FASTINSTALL and INSTALLCONDFEATURE are both Secure and Admin.
2. Using the Windows Installer ACTION or EXECUTEACTION properties. In this case the condition is something like:

   `<Condition Level="1">( VersionNT >= 601 AND NOT FASTINSTALL = "1" ) OR ACTION = "ADMIN"</Condition>`

Neither of these seem to work. Am I just missing something here, or is there a different, better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A feature with Feature/@Level="0" will never be installed in an admin install, per the MSI SDK:

> During an administrative installation,
>   the installer creates a source image
>   for all features in the product except
>   those feature with 0 in the Level
>   column of the Feature table.

So you need to reverse your logic; set the feature level to something greater than zero and use Conditions to set it to zero for non-admin installs.